# Teleport a player away from certain entities?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Got multiple armor stands with the name `_safezone_`, what I want to achieve is to basically have "safe domes" where no players can get in, except for the ones already inside.

So I tried setting up a command which teleports everyone near the armor stand named `_safezone_` to spawn.

```
/execute @e[name=_safezone_] ~ ~ ~ /tp @a[r=128,rm=150] @e[c=1,name=_spawn_]
```

And it returns with an error that it coudn't execute the command as the entity `_safezone_`. Is there a workaround - without spawning commandblocks everywhere? (or am I missing something?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... seems like I mixed up "r" and "rm", rm stands for the minimum radius, not maximum, just swap it around, correction;

```
/execute @e[name=_safezone_] ~ ~ ~ /tp @a[r=150,rm=128] @e[c=1,name=_spawn_]
```

Comment: It's OK to answer your own question, but we usually prefer to have the answer in the answer instead of in the question.

Answer (score -2):

Use barrier blocks, theyre invisible, and cannot be broken. Not a fix, but a solution

Comment: How does that help someone teleport away from things?